# Change mp3 bpm on client side using javascript

Tags: javascript, client, html5-audio, web-audio-api

Is it possible to change a full length song (3+ mins) bpm using javascript on the client side with webaudio api or other library?
If so, how?

Thx,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the time but not the pitch and you want to put in the work you can write a time compression program [like this](http://vexflow.com/vexwarp/).

If you simply want to speed up a sound (and change its pitch) you can do this:

```
audioInput.playbackRate.value = 2;  // 2 times speed
```